# Compare 2 CSV files using daff package in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Hey guys I have this package for comparing two CSV files called [DAFF for R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/daff/versions/0.3.5) which  I have used in R and its very easy to use in R language though I was asking if there is same way I can implement it in python, here is the python version [Daff for python](https://pypi.org/project/daff/) which I am struggling understanding on how to use it in comparing two csv files, please help?